# How to fix "cannot import name 'get_seomoz_data' from 'api' " error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypi

I have tried to get the Alexa ranking for a given website. I used PyPI's seolib library and installed it in my environment using **!pip install seolib --use**r command. After executing ***alexa_rank = seolib.get_alexa('http://google.com')*** code line, I got the following error.

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'
```

Then I installed api module using **!pip install api --user** command. Then after I got this import error and I don't have an idea of how to solve this error. Please somebody help on this.

```py
import seolib

alexa_rank = seolib.get_alexa('http://google.com')
print(alexa_rank)
```

```py
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-b46efa0fce9a> in <module>
----> 1 import seolib
      2 
      3 alexa_rank = seolib.get_alexa('http://google.com')
      4 print(alexa_rank)

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seolib/__init__.py in <module>
      4 
      5 
----> 6 from api import get_seomoz_data
      7 from api import get_alexa
      8 from api import get_semrush

ImportError: cannot import name 'get_seomoz_data' from 'api' (/home/mylap/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/api/__init__.py)
```

I'm using **Python 3.7.3** version on my environment.

Answer (score 1):

[seolib](https://pypi.org/project/seolib/#history) version 0.1.3, last release was in 2013 year. Homepage returns error 404. Doesn't look good. Old, outdated, abandoned.

The code `from api import` was relative import in Python 2.7, changed to absolute import in Python 3. Overall the code seems to be Python2-only.

Comment: Thank you for the info. My ultimate goal here is to get Alexa ranking for a given site. Can you suggest a good library I can use to achieve my goal here?